# Regex: uppercase words that don´t start with a hyphen

Tags: regex

I need to match all uppercase words that don't start with a hyphen.
There are multiple uppercase words in each line.

examples:

```
,BOAT -> match
BANANA, -> match
WATER -> match
-ER -> no match because of hyphen
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `\b(?<!-)[A-Z]+\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(?<!-)[A-Z]+\b
\b(?<!-)\p{Lu}+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BsopHx/1)

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!-)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `-` immediately to the left of the current position
- `[A-Z]+` / `\p{Lu}+` - one or more uppercase letters (`\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase Unicode letters)
- `\b` - word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to match all uppercase words that don't start with a hyphen.

You may use this regex:

```
(?<!\S)[^-A-Z\s]*[A-Z]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcISDS/2)

**RegEx Explained:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Make sure we don't have a non-space before current position
- `[^-A-Z\s]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not hyphen and not uppercase letters and not whitespaces
- `[A-Z]+`: Match 1+ uppercase letters

Comment: Thank you @anubhava but this doesn't work for me. This returns only the first match for each line.

Comment: Do you have multiple uppercase words per line? You example shows only one word per line? Also what is your regex flavor?

Comment: sorry i wasn't specific enough in the question. Yes i multiple uppercase words per line. I am using the Python3 regex library.

Comment: ok then `(?<!\S)[^-A-Z\s]*[A-Z]+` should work for you